# How can I resolve AWS mock test with singleton classes

Tags: amazon-web-services, ecmascript-6, jestjs

when I execute Jest in Javascript test with AWS mock via npm, it will be Failure.
because I use singleton class.

The difference like here.

「module.exports = Users;」 or 「module.exports = new Users();」

I guess AWS mock doesn't work with singleton class.

in that cause, how should I do to solve this problem?

```
'use strick';

var aws = require('aws-sdk')
aws.config.update({region:'ap-northeast-1'})

class Users {

    constructor() {
        this.table = 'Users'
        this.dynamodb = new aws.DynamoDB()
    }

    getData(email) {
        let params = {
            TableName: this.table,
            Key      : { 'email': {'S':email} }
        }

        return this.dynamodb.getItem(params).promise()
    }
}
// module.exports = Users // ← this will be success.
module.exports = new Users(); // ← this will be failure.
```

```
'use strict';

var aws = require('aws-sdk-mock'),
    users = require('./user'),
    chai = require('chai'),
    path = require('path'),
    should = chai.should(),
    input = 'test@gmail.com',
    usersObj;

aws.setSDK(path.resolve('node_modules/aws-sdk'));

describe('All Tests', function () {
    // this.timeout(0);
    beforeEach(function () {
        aws.mock('DynamoDB', 'getItem', function (params, callback) {
            callback(null, {Item: {email: params.Key.email.S}});
        });

        // usersObj = new users(); ← this will be success.
        usersObj = users; // ← this will be failure.
    });

    it('getData', function (done) {
        usersObj.getData(input).then(function (res) {

            console.log(res);

            res.Item.email.should.equal(input);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this pattern too.

```
'use strict';

var aws = require('aws-sdk-mock'),
    users = require('./user'),
    chai = require('chai'),
    path = require('path'),
    should = chai.should(),
    input = 'test@gmail.com',
    usersObj;

const awsObject = require('aws-sdk');

aws.setSDK(path.resolve('node_modules/aws-sdk'));

describe('All Tests', function () {
    // this.timeout(0);
    beforeEach(function () {
        aws.mock('DynamoDB', 'getItem', function (params, callback) {
            callback(null, {Item: {email: params.Key.email.S}});
        });

        // it will be resolve problem by creating new AWS instance.
        users.dynamodb = new awsObject.DynamoDB();
    });

    it('getData', function (done) {
        users.getData(input).then(function (res) {

            console.log(res);

            res.Item.email.should.equal(input);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
module.exports = new Users();
```

...means that a `Users` object will get created as soon as the code runs...and it runs as soon as `user.js` is `required`.

This line:

```
users = require('./user')
```

...is at the top of your test file and this line:

```
aws.mock('DynamoDB', 'getItem', function (params, callback) {
  callback(null, {Item: {email: params.Key.email.S}});
});
```

...is in a `beforeEach`...

...which means that `user.js` is `required` and runs before the mock has been created...which causes the test to fail.

---

If you are going to export an instance of `Users` then you just need to make sure you don't `require` the `user.js` file in your test until *after* you have set up your mock:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk-mock'),
  chai = require('chai'),
  path = require('path'),
  input = 'test@gmail.com',
  usersObj;
chai.should()

aws.setSDK(path.resolve('node_modules/aws-sdk'));

describe('All Tests', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    aws.mock('DynamoDB', 'getItem', function (params, callback) {
      callback(null, { Item: { email: params.Key.email.S } });
    });  // <= set up the mock first...

    usersObj = require('./user');  // <= ...then require user.js
  });

  it('getData', function (done) {
    usersObj.getData(input).then(function (res) {
      res.Item.email.should.equal(input);  // Success!
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call the aws client inside the class constructor

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(){
    this.dynamodb = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "us-west-2" });
  }
...
```

In the test file you must create a new instance of your class just after call de AWSMock. Example:

```
it('Should save on dinamoDB with param atributes void()', async () => {
  AWSMock.mock('DynamoDB.DocumentClient', 'update', function (params, callback){
    callback(null, { Attributes: { currentValue: 1 } } );
  });
  AWSMock.mock('DynamoDB.DocumentClient', 'put', function (params, callback){
    callback(null, true);
  });

  const myClass = new MyClass();
...
```